# Como utilizar un único campo de un JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Hola tengo un codigo el cual manda una solicitud POST a una API, esta devuelve un JSON, este JSON lo mapeo en variables con @JsonProperty, quisiera saber como puedo utilizar uno de los campos que me devuelve el JSON  en otros metodos. Os dejos los codigos a continuacion.

SOLICITUD POST:

```
@PostMapping("/hostedTokenizationSession")
@CrossOrigin
public CreateHostedTokenizationSessionResponse hostedTokenizationSession() throws AuthenticationException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    //Crear un nuevo objeto HttpClient
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .build();

    HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(getRequest(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(response.body(), CreateHostedTokenizationSessionResponse.class);

}
```

CLASE DONDE MAPEO LAS VARIABLES

```
public class CreateHostedTokenizationSessionResponse {

@JsonProperty("hostedTokenizationUrl")
private String hostedTokenizationUrl;

@JsonProperty("partialRedirectUrl")
private String partialRedirectUrl;

@JsonProperty("hostedTokenizationId")
private String hostedTokenizationId;

@JsonProperty("invalidTokens")
private String[] invalidTokens;

@JsonProperty("expiredCardTokens")
private String[] expiredCardTokens;
```

}

JSON QUE RECIBO

```
{
"hostedTokenizationUrl": "https://payment.preprod.direct.ingenico.com/hostedtokenization/tokenization/form/6f8e2c7b9659483b8d47005797a63a1b",
"partialRedirectUrl": "preprod.direct.ingenico.com/hostedtokenization/tokenization/form/6f8e2c7b9659483b8d47005797a63a1b",
"hostedTokenizationId": "6f8e2c7b9659483b8d47005797a63a1b",
"invalidTokens": [],
"expiredCardTokens": []
```

}

Quisera extraer la variable hostedTokenizationId, para despues usarla en otras solicitudes, pero por mas que pruebo, al extraerla cambia. Ayudarme porfi. Gracias.